# Why does Racket report that π is rational?

Tags: racket, rational-numbers

As any secondary math student can attest, pi is irrational.

And yet:

```
Welcome to Racket v5.3.6.
> pi
3.141592653589793
> (rational? pi)
#t
```

Is this because the *representation* of pi, in the underlying machine's floating point format, is of limited precision and therefore can always be expressed as some p/q where q is 10^n, and n is the representational precision ?

If so, how could any number thrown about by Racket (or other similarly-behaving scheme) ever be considered anything but rational?  And hence, why bother with the `rational?` function?

**UPDATE:** Even `(rational? (sqrt 3))` reports `#t`

Comment: Do you know some *number* for which Racket reports that `rational?` gives `#f` ? BTW is `pi` predefined? How is it documented (as the real pi, or as some approximation of it)?

Comment: I do not.  I'm new to scheme, was surprised that (rational? 4.1) reported true, and then thought I'd go with pi as my nuclear option.  My head promptly asploded.

Comment: I even tried a (leibniz err) function that I found online that computes approximations of pi to within the given error.  Its result also was declared to be rational.

Comment: That looks to me like a rational number because, as you said, it is only `pi` to a few decimal places. My guess is that some results of functions, for instance some square roots like `sqrt(3)`, would be irrational when calculated, and the function would recognize that.

Comment: BTW, I would ask that on some forum or mailing list dedicated to Racket. FWIW, `guile` (and `bigloo`) don't even know about `pi`, and is also a Scheme implementation.

Comment: @the_storyteller (rational? (sqrt 3)) => #t

Comment: I guess not then.

Comment: `(rational? (sqrt 3)) => #t` because all real numbers other than the infinities and NaNs are rational.

Comment: Many numbers supported by many Schemes are not rational: in particular no complex number with a non-zero imaginary part is rational.  Thus, for instance, `(rational? (sqrt -1))` is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number returned by `pi` is rational because the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/numbers.html#%28tech._rational._number%29) says so. Specifically it says:

> All numbers are complex numbers. Some of them are real numbers, and all of the real numbers that can be represented are also rational numbers, except for +inf.0 (positive infinity), +inf.f (single-precision variant), -inf.0 (negative infinity), -inf.f (single-precision variant), +nan.0 (not-a-number), and +nan.f (single-precision variant). Among the rational numbers, some are integers, because round applied to the number produces the same number.

So your hunch is right. All *representable* real numbers are indeed rational (except for the infinities and NaNs) because, yes, numbers are stored in fixed-size registers so the machine isn't going to store an irrational number.

As to *why* the Racket designers bothered with a `rational?` function, that is a good question. Many languages like Julia and Clojure have a real, actual, honest-to-goodness rational datatype. Racket doesn't, so, as you suspect, it does *seem* silly to define a near-complete subset of the reals as rationals.

But you know, it *just may be* convenient to have a way to talk about a non-NaN, non-Infinity value. I would have called it `finite`, but Racket calls it `rational`.

Comment: After thinking about it more, I suppose a robust `rational?` would risk boiling the oceans...

Comment: Agreed. I'm curious about whether that is even computable. One would need to know what functions like `sqrt` were _intended_ to mean. And I don't think getting into people heads like that can rationally be expected of a language.

Comment: Racket inherited `rational?` from Scheme, which allowed implementations a lot of flexibility in the numeric system. I think other Schemes might have had more reals that weren't rational, numbers that weren't complex (quaternions?), etc.

Comment: Very true. We were commenting though on the difficulty/impossibility?
 of detecting calls such as `sqrt(3)` and attempting to make THAT value return `#f` when passed to `rational?` Attempting to determine which sqrts, which sines, which cosines etc really are irrational wouldn't be possible especially when there are user-defined transcendentals that could be created. At any rate, yes, good point that there's nothing really "wrong" or even _that_ bizzare with Racket's implementation.